# How to check internet connection status over 3G connection?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have the following method:

```
public static bool IsNetworkConnected()
{
    ConnectionProfile InternetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    IReadOnlyList<ConnectionProfile> connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();
    if (InternetConnectionProfile == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

It works fine when I'm connected to the internet in a typical way - via LAN cable or Wi-Fi. When I'm using my 3G USB modem it returns false (`InternectConnectionProfile` is null). Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: I would usually recommend that you ignore the current connection state, and just attempt whatever it is that you want to do over the internet (preferably, in a background thread) - then, report to the user if you've been unable to accomplish the task after (time out period/number of retries). Connections can drop between checking for their presence and using them, or half way through whatever task you're doing. Since you *have* to write code to cope with these situations *anyway*, save yourself some coding and avoid pre-checking.

Answer (score 4):

You may consider pinging a server on the internet. This is not the 100% answer to your question but may be helpful from a different point of view.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

using (Ping Packet = new Ping()) 
{
    if (Packet.Send(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 1000, new byte[] { 0 }).Status ==   IPStatus.Success))
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Since packets sometimes seem to stop for coffeee between routers and are lost, I'd try pinging at least 3 times before reporting "Connection down", otherwise I concur with this straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public static bool IsConnectedToInternet()
{
        ConnectionProfile connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
        return (connectionProfile!=null && connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/a7ba014c-3a31-4ff3-ba10-0c835305828b/