# Network checking in WinRT(C# implementation)

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

How we can check the status of network in windows 8 metro application. ie the availability of different networks(3g,4g, wifi etc)

Comment: Check out my topic. I believe you'll need that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11757111/how-to-check-internet-connection-status-over-3g-connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/d8e76732-19d3-47b3-840f-70d87c75ce9f), I think this is the simplest form of checking network availability in windows 8.

```
 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/d8e76732-19d3-47b3-840f-70d87c75ce9f
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this [sample download](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Network-Information-Sample-63aaa201) help you....