# Check internet connection (availability) in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How to check internet connection availability in Windows 8,C# development ? I looked at MSDN but page has been deleted.

Comment: *Duplicate of:* http://stackoverflow.com/a/11797256/763026. Should be Closed.

Comment: You would do exactly what you would do on Windows 7, Windows Vista, or Windows XP attempt to get the content and if it failed display an error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network checking in WinRT(C# implementation)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797133/network-checking-in-winrtc-implementation)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I use this snippet without problems:

```
public static bool IsInternet()
{
    ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    bool internet = connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;
    return internet;
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, how can I achieve the same thing in windows phone 8? I get get "Method or operation not implemented" exception in windows phone 8 using your snippet. Thanks in advance

Comment: This does not work if there are multiple connections, which e.g. may be the case in the emulators. Use the code from Joshua Heller below, which fixes the problem.

Comment: Works with Windows 10 SDK 1803 Build 17134

Answer (score 10):

I had to use GetConnectionProfiles() and GetInternetConnectionProfile() to make it work across all devices.

```
class ConnectivityUtil
{
    internal static bool HasInternetConnection()
    {            
        var connections = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles().ToList();
        connections.Add(NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile());

        foreach (var connection in connections)
        {
            if (connection == null)
                continue;

            if (connection.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This also works if there are multiple internet connections - which may be the case in the Win 10 emulator and other circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone Following code may be usefull:

```
var networkInformation = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();    
if (networkInformation.Count == 0)    
{    
  //no network connection    
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. networkInformation.Count.ToString() returns 15 in Aereo mode...