# Try-catch block to check internet connection

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am making an windows 8 app which involves internet connectivity.
Before starting with the functions of app, I want to check whether the device is connected to the internet or not.
Could anyone tell the try catch block statements associated with the process.
Thank You in advance!

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?  Even something like just making a request to google.com and checking for a valid response?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625304/check-internet-connection-availability-in-windows-8

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to check for Internet connectivity using .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031824/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-internet-connectivity-using-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use something like:

```
public static bool CheckForInternetConnection()
{
   try
   {
      using (var mobileClient = new WebClient())
      using (var webConnection = mobileClient.OpenRead("http://www.somewebsite.com"))
      {
         return true;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

The `WebClient` class lives in the `System.Net.WebClient` namespace, so you will need to add a reference to it.  The documentation for `WebClient` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank You! But "WebClient" does not work in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2031831/884862  the original answer, top search result for --c# check internet--

Comment: Your point being?  I used that answer (which I also Google'd) in a solution I was working on and copied out the code above from said solution.

Comment: a `WebClient` just for testing internet connection? And pinging an external site? this is plain **bad**. please use something like this instead : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29701786/953684