# How to detect windows Store App is Online (for Sync) or Offline (to fetch data from sqlite) like javascript we use navigator.online?

Tags: sqlite, windows-store-apps

I need to detect app is Online or Offline.
According to network availability I can sync data to sqlite and if app is Offline run app on sqlite data.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool IsInternet()
{
    ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    bool internet = connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;
    return internet;
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625304/check-internet-connection-availability-in-windows-8).