# How to prevent webexception message?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

My C# windows forms app downloads a short string form an url. It parses the string and shows info. It is used purely for this. Sort of a pop up program. I am using this:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
string json = wc.DownloadString(url);
//parse the string
//show windows form with the gathered data 
this.Show()
}
```

My problem is, when there is no internet connection, unhandled exception error pops up. I think that I need to prevent this error message and just keep the program rolling until the connection is back up. How to prevent the message and keep it running?

Comment: There is a well known way to check if the internet connection is available (albeit not always correct) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625304/check-internet-connection-availability-in-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

Using a [`try .. catch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) block construct like

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
try {
string json = wc.DownloadString(url);
//parse the string
//show windows form with the gathered data 
this.Show()
}
catch(exception ex) { //Log the exception with datetime }
}
```

Comment: catch should prevent the message? how to log the exception? i am quite new with all this

Comment: @JonasKazlauskas, try searching in Google you will get million of samples.

Comment: @Rahul it looks like the application should be catching WebException, instead of general Exception. That way application could return a response with a message, that there is no internet connection.